# Monitor (mutationobserver)for text change in an element in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is it possible to monitor (using mutationobserver) for text change and return the new and the old text, in for example the following situation:
`<span class="ss1">1</span>` changes to `<span class="ss1">4</span>`. What I need is for puppeteer to return the old value of **1** and the new value of **4** when it changes.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: onchange="myFunction()"

Comment: @Ess on a `span` element, that's not going to do much...

Comment: You can inject functions into the page with puppeteer via [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args); just inject two functions; one that adds a MutationObserver event handler, and one that receives the event triggered by that handler.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Can you please supply example code?

Comment: @abruski Please show what you've done so far (a minimal code to reproduce the problem with MutationObserver that you seem to have).

Answer (score 1):

This script should be enough:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://example.com/');

    // memorize old value
    const oldValue = await page.$eval('.ss1', el => el.textContent);

    // wait until the .ss1 value changes
    while (oldValue == await page.$eval('.ss1', el => el.textContent))
    {
        page.waitFor(1000); // Wait for a second
    }

    // memorize new value
    const newValue = await page.$eval('.ss1', el => el.textContent);

    // output them
    console.log("Old value: " + oldValue);
    console.log("New value: " + newValue);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Please note: I suppose there's only one `.ss1` element on the page.

Comment: Can't mutationobserver be used? Polling is not an option.

Comment: Pity you didn't note that polling is not an option. Of course MutationObserver can be used, just do as Heretic Monkey suggested in his comment.